# How to show that $v$ is invertible in $H\ $?

Tags: hopf-algebras, quantum-groups

Let $(H, \mu, \eta, \Delta, \varepsilon, S)$ be a Hopf algebra. Let $\mathcal F \in H \otimes H$ be an invertible element such that

$(1)$ $(\mathcal F \otimes 1) (\Delta \otimes \text {id}) (\mathcal F) = (1 \otimes \mathcal F) (\text {id} \otimes \Delta) (\mathcal F),$

$(2)$ $(\varepsilon \otimes \text {id}) (\mathcal F) = 1 = (\text {id} \otimes \varepsilon) (\mathcal F).$

Then the element $v = \mu (\text {id} \otimes S) (\mathcal F) \in H$ is invertible with inverse being given by $\mu (S \otimes \text {id}) (\mathcal F^{-1}).$

**My Attempt** $:$

Since $\Delta$ and $\varepsilon$ are algebra homomorphisms it follows that

$(\Delta \otimes \text {id}) (\mathcal F^{-1}) (\mathcal F^{-1} \otimes 1) = (\text {id} \otimes \Delta) (\mathcal F^{-1}) (1 \otimes \mathcal F^{-1}),$

and,

$(\varepsilon \otimes \text {id}) (\mathcal F^{-1}) = 1 = (\text {id} \otimes \varepsilon) (\mathcal F^{-1}).$

Using these relations and the axioms of Hopf algebra I managed to show that $v u = 1$ where $u = \mu (S \otimes \text {id}) (\mathcal F^{-1}).$ But I am having hard time showing that $u v = 1.$

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

**Source** $:$ *A Guide to Quantum Groups* by Vyjayanthi Chari and Andrew Pressley.