# How to compute the fundamental group of $X_n\ $?

Tags: algebraic-topology

[image]

How to find the fundamental group of $X_n\ $?

I am trying to use Van Kampen but for that I really need to know what is $\partial D^2/ \widetilde\ $?

Is it some well-known space?

Comment: When $n=2$, for example, do you end up identifying (among other identifications) all $e^{-i\pi/2^k}$ as a single point (together with $1$) or am I understanding the quotient wrong?

Comment: Please typeset the problem statement in your post, do *not* keep in in an embedded screenshot. From our guidelines for [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992) your post: *The key parts of your question should not be in an embedded image such as a photo/screenshot/etc., such images are not searchable, they are not accessible to those using screen readers, and they don't show up in question summaries.*

Comment: @LeeMosher$:$ Are you the one who downvoted?

Comment: @Thorgott$:$ What was my last question? My last question is shown to be https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4737406/512080

Comment: I had previously misread the equivalence relation. I suspect there might be a typo in it, but if there isn't, the space $\partial D^2/\sim$ is indiscrete, hence contractible.

Comment: @Thorgott$:$ Could you please explain it a bit more? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try showing the the equivalence class represented by $1\in S^1$ only has the entire space has an open neighborhood, but is also dense. This implies that the space is indiscrete.